# Is it possible to write on whole device before mount?

Tags: mount, usb-drive, unmount, eject

When a USB storage (such as an SD card) is connected to my Ubuntu desktop, it is mounted automatically as `/dev/sdc1`. If it is **ejected** or **safely removed**, `/dev/sdc1` goes out from `/dev/` folder and `/dev/sdc` remains, but it is not writable.
Is it possible to write directly on `/dev/sdc`?

Comment: From experience with my own memory card readers, I suspect, that the remaining device is only a placeholder for possibly connected memory cards. What do you want achieve by writing to it?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I need to write it to completely delete any data byte in the storage.

Comment: Please clarify your intent in your question to avoid [The XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In that case you may want to just unmount the file system and not eject the entire device.

Comment: Unlike Windows, Linux can properly treat removable devices with multiple partitions. sdX is the device node and sdXy is the y-th partition on the X-th device. If you want to write to the device directly without mounting a partition with a filesystem you can use `dd`. If you want to "zero" your USB use: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc`. Be sure to run `sync` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdc1` is a "device file", and represents the first partition of the device `/dev/sdc`.

It represents the whole partition as a single raw file (i.e. as the sequence of bytes as written in the partition).

This is not something understandable in terms of directories / files without interpreting such sequence as a filesystem.

What you see "out of `/dev/`" is the mount point of the filesystem stored in `/dev/sdc1`, and it's a directory hierarchy result of interpreting the raw content of the partition accordingly to such filesystem.

This is needed in order to read / write directories / files; Ubuntu knows how the filesystem works and will be able to handle the partition properly and accordingly to the filesystem in use, in such a way that data can be read / written to it keeping the filesystem consistent.